# How to run an LLVM pass with the new PassManager

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I'm trying to create an `LLVM` pass that would add a call to `printf` at the beginning of each function. It works OK with `opt` but I cannot manage to have it to run while I'm compiling the target `C` which I want to have modified. I think it doesn't work because I did not register my `pass` properly. I tried using `RegisterStandardPasses` but I cannot make to compile. Please note that I want to use the new `PassManager`.

I tried the `pass` in this way `clang-13 -v -Xclang -load -Xclang ./build/lib/Test.so bc/a.c`

So far the code is the following:

```
#include "Test.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/Statistic.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/Passes/PassBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/Passes/PassPlugin.h"
#include "llvm/Support/Debug.h"

#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace llvm;


#define DEBUG_TYPE "test"
char TestPass::ID = 0;

static std::unique_ptr<IRBuilder<>> Builder;

PreservedAnalyses TestPass::run(Module& M, ModuleAnalysisManager& AM)
{

    errs() << M.getName() << "\n";
    
    for(Function& F : M) {
        runOnFunction(F);
    }
    return PreservedAnalyses::all();
}

PreservedAnalyses TestPass::runOnFunction(Function& F)
{
    
    if(F.getBasicBlockList().size() > 0) {
        
        IRBuilder<> IRB(&*F.getBasicBlockList().front().getFirstInsertionPt());

        

        std::string var_name = "100";

        Function* func_printf = F.getParent()->getFunction("printf");

        if(func_printf == nullptr) {
            FunctionType* functionType = FunctionType::get(IntegerType::get(F.getParent()->getContext(), 64), true);

            func_printf = Function::Create(functionType, GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage, "printf", F.getParent());
            func_printf->setCallingConv(CallingConv::C);
        }

        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "Calling function: " << F.getName().str() << "\n";

        Value* str = IRB.CreateGlobalStringPtr(ss.str());
        std::vector<Value*> int32_call_params;
        int32_call_params.push_back(str);

        IRB.CreateCall(func_printf, int32_call_params);
    }

    return PreservedAnalyses::none();
}

PreservedAnalyses TestPass::runOnGVariable(GlobalVariable& G)
{
    outs() << G << "\n";
    return PreservedAnalyses::all();
}

bool PipelineParsingCB(StringRef Name, ModulePassManager& MPM, ArrayRef<PassBuilder::PipelineElement>)
{
    if(Name == "test") {
        MPM.addPass(TestPass());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void RegisterCB(PassBuilder& PB)
{
    PB.registerPipelineParsingCallback(PipelineParsingCB);
}

extern "C" ::llvm::PassPluginLibraryInfo LLVM_ATTRIBUTE_WEAK llvmGetPassPluginInfo()
{
    return { LLVM_PLUGIN_API_VERSION, "TEST", "v0.1", RegisterCB };
}

// this causes a compile error
static RegisterStandardPasses Y(
    PassManagerBuilder::EP_EarlyAsPossible,
    [](const PassManagerBuilder &Builder,
       legacy::PassManagerBase &PM) { PM.add(new TestPass()); });
```

The error that I have is the following:

```
‘RegisterStandardPasses’ does not name a type
   88 | static RegisterStandardPasses Y(
```

```
expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
   91 |        legacy::PassManagerBase &PM) { PM.add(new SepPass()); });
      |                                                               ^
```

Any idea on how to fix it?

Thanks a lot

PS: I saw the question [Adding a simple printf in a LLVM pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49558395/adding-a-simple-printf-in-a-llvm-pass) but it is not exactly what I need.

Comment: Shouldn't you `#include "llvm/Transforms/IPO/PassManagerBuilder.h"` for `RegisterStandardPasses` class to be recognized?

Comment: Could be. I'm still in the learning phase... I'll try it asap. If you want to put  a "real" answer please feel free to do it with a demo so i can accept it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Oh, no worries, thanks so much. I just did a quick google search for `RegisterStandardPasses` but didn't even try it myself, so that's not really worth an answer. I just hope it helps though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For those landing here fter the drop of he legacy pass manager, I put an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54447985/how-to-automatically-register-and-load-modern-pass-in-clang/75999804#75999804)